# Learning how to synchronize execution of parent and child process using pipes in C

Tags: c, synchronization, pipe

I have this program

```
int main()
{
  char *s, buf[1024];
  int ret, stat;
  s  = "Use for syncing\n";

  ret = fork();

  if (ret == 0)
  {
    printf("Child line 1\n");
    printf("Child line 2\n");
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf("Parent line 1\n");
    printf("Parent line 2\n");
    wait(&stat);
  }
}
```

The output of this program is currently

```
Parent line 1
Parent line 2
Child line 1
Child line 2
```

but I need to alter the code in order for the child and parent processes to synchronize, so the desired output is:

```
Child line 1
Parent line 1
Child line 2
Parent line 2
```

I'm having trouble conceptually understanding how to do this, I know when `ret = fork()` is called it will return an integer that is not equal to 0, thus, it will go to the else part of the if-else, then ret's value will become 0 after the process returns successfully and it will go to the if part of the if-else. I've tried to use `wait(&ret)` inside the else statement so that the program will wait for `ret` to return 0 but this only returns the opposite of the current output. This is where my understanding of synchronization ends so I am stuck on this.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use explicit synchronisation between parent and child processes. For example you can read/write to pipes to ensure the processes have the execution order you want - parent reads pipe which blocks until child writes, then child reads pipe which blocks until parent writes, etc.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you mentioned pipes in the title. So yeah, that seems like the way you have been asked to do it and you should at least attempt to create and use a pipe. If you get stuck then do a search - this exercise has been asked many times before.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will try that.